# Editing a Library (App) Template

Tags: office-365

I have created library template by saving as a template a custom document library. I now want to edit that template. I am unable to find a way to edit it. Is this possible or do I have to edit a document library and save it again?

Ideally, I would want the change to the template to apply to all document libraries created with this template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a new library template in order to create new libraries using the revised definition.  You can't edit the list template from the web user interface.

Also, template changes would not apply to existing library instances created from the template.  Templates don't work that way in SharePoint.  Think of a list template as a one-time creation set of instructions. Once your library is created from the instructions it has no association to the template that was involved in creating it.

Comment: Should I be looking at custom content types instead?

Comment: Content types don't have an impact on list settings. So, it depends on what you are trying to do.  I suggest creating a new question with additional details about what you are trying to do.